# Get latest version of WebIOPi into Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, webiopi

The latest version of Webiopi is WebIOPi-0.7.1.tar.gz. It's on SourceForge. I have an earlier version installed on my Pi. I'd like to update it to the newer version. I don't know how to do that.

Also, I can't seem to find the webiopi.js client. Any ideas on that?

New to Linux. Thanks for your help. Pi is up and running, including WiFi, Apache 2.2, and secure terminal login (xterm?).

Comment: I think I got it. I downloaded the tar.gz file from SourceForge, then followed the tutorial directions on the WebIOPi web site. It seemed to me that last time I installed it I didn't need to download manually. Oh well....
Still, any idea about webiopi.js?

Comment: Found webiopi.js.... It was in the htscripts directory for both versions.